# How to enter different types parameters into function to return one type data?

Tags: java

l want to enter different types parameters (such as:int,float,double,long) into function to return one type data(such as:string).

Here l just wanna make a function to turn different type data to be string data.

Comment: Sounds like you should probably have multiple overloads for the same method. Either that, or accept `Number` or `Object` as your parameter type.

Comment: Could you add some more context? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: public static getString (int i,float f,double d)---->return string i,   string f,  string d

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    public static <T extends Number> String getString(T element) {
        return element.toString();
    }


System.out.println(getString(new BigInteger("34234523")));
System.out.println(getString(234));
```

Comment: l want to make a method just like:  public static getString (int i,float f,double d)---->return string i, string f, string d                                                        
can  “Function<Number, String> myFunction = e”   make it?

Comment: Yeah, just use e.toString()

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you were asking about a function that does this.  Here's another way to do it using generics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your requirement correctly but may be you should do something like,

```
static String fun(Object object)
{
    if (object==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else 
        return new String(object.toString());
}
```

and make call like,

```
String val = fun(3.4);
```

Comment: Thank you!     ///////////////                                                                                         public static getString (int i,float f,double d)---->return string i, string f, string d               //////////////////enter three parameter "int i,float f,double d"  at the same time!        /////////          not   one time one type

Comment: The key point is : enter many different parameters "int i,float f,double d,········" at the same time!    /////////////please  help  me!    thank  you!!!

Comment: This will work, but notice that the method will take in any Object.  It will take a String, an arrayList, basically anything.  Generics is a more precise way to get the job done.

Comment: @JackChen Chen do you want to a method to take n number of parameters? then what do you want to return? Same number of parameters as input? Confirm that then I can provide you the answer. And if you liked the solution vote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to:

1. Convert number types to data types
2. Return multiple strings

No. 1 can be achieved with:

```
double num = 123.123123;    
return "" + num;
//or
int i = 5;
String s = "int: " + i;
return s;
```

Number datatypes will "convert themselves" to strings on their own if you use `"" + num`, using it's built in `.toString()` method.

---

Based on your comment you want to return multiple strings of each input parameter.

> public static getString (int i,float f,double d)---->return string i, string f, string d

In order to return multiple strings from one variable, typically we would split the function into several functions:

```
String intToString(int n) {
  return " + n;
}

String intToFloat(float n) {
  return "" + n;
}

String intToDouble(double n) {
  return "" + n;
}
```

Alternatively if you really want to jam all these different functionalities into one function this can be achieved with an [Array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm).

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int i = 1;
    //the f on the end of this number is an implicit cast
    float f = 5.5f;
    double d = 6.123;
    String[] a = getString(i,f,d);
    System.out.println("int: " + a[0]);
    System.out.println("float: " + a[1]);
    System.out.println("double: " + a[2]);
}
public static String[] getString(int i, float f, double d) {
    int numberOfReturns = 3;
    String[] a = new String[numberOfReturns];
    a[0] = "" + i;
    a[1] = "" + f;
    a[2] = "" + d;
    return a;
}
```